# #if and #elif doesn't work as intended in Cpp

Tags: c-preprocessor, definition, using-directives

I am trying to make some sort of easy way to define mcu that I use, and by defining mcu, different header files should be included. I tried doing it with `#if` and `#elif` directives :

```
#include "Parameters.h"

#if MCU_IN_USE == ESP32_S3_MINI_1
   #include "ESP32_S3_MINI_1_PINOUT.h"
#elif MCU_IN_USE == ESP32_S3_WROOM
   #include "ESP32_S3_WROOM_PINOUT.h"
#endif
```

and in `Parameters.h` file I defined MCU like this:

```
//#define MCU_IN_USE         ESP32_S3_MINI_1
#define MCU_IN_USE         ESP32_S3_WROOM
```

I plan to uncomment the one I use and comment the other one, but the problem is that no matter which define is uncommented, I always get first option in `#if` statement even though, I am using `#elif` define:
[image]

What causes this problem?

Comment: What are `ESP32_S3_MINI_1` and `ESP32_S3_WROOM` defined to?

Comment: fixed it. I don't know why, but I did not defined them to anything, so basically I defined a MCU_IN_USE to nothing. Very shameful mistake

Comment: :-) Can happen to anyone! Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

So basically I defined `MCU_IN_USE` to `ESP32_S3_WROOM` and `ESP32_S3_WROOM` is defined to nothing, it is not constant or string or anything, it's just an empty definition. I don't know why I did this, because it super basic mistake, but fixed it by including this

```
#define ESP32_S3_MINI_1     0
#define ESP32_S3_WROOM      1
```